# Why do we only solve for $0$ on the numerator of this fraction?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have [this function](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-intercepts-calculator/intercepts%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(x%5Cleft(x-4%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cleft(%5Cleft(x-1%5Cright)%5Cleft(x-5%5Cright)%5Cleft(x%2B2%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D) where I need to find the $x$-intercepts

[image]

I see they are $x = 0, 4$. And know that this is found by doing: 
$x=0, (x-4) = 0$ [Solve].

But why is this only done for the numerator?

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}=0$ if and only if $a=0$ (*and $b$ is not zero, as it would be undefined in that case*).  In your case $\frac{x(x-4)}{(x-1)(x-5)(x+2)}=0$ if and only if the numerator $x(x-4)$ is zero.  The denominator equalling zero won't give the intercepts, but rather the locations of the vertical asymptotes or [poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles).

Comment: @JMoravitz would it be true to say that a fraction can only = 0 if numerator = 0?

Comment: Yes, again with the caveat that the denominator must be defined and nonzero there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking why we set only the numerator equal to 0 and not the denominator, recall that $0$ divided by any nonzero number is $0$. Similarly, any number divided by $0$ is undefined.

Therefore in your case, the fraction is only equal to $0$ when its numerator is equal to $0$ and it's denominator is not equal to $0$, as having a denominator equal to $0$ (which is akin to dividing by $0$) would render the expression undefined.